# How to iterate through directories to process raster files without a loop with the apply family in R

Tags: r

I have raster files (.tif) inside different folders (those are my models). I need to import them into individual objects and process them for creating an array (I'll use "abind" for that).

I do have a large number of models thus creating a huge array dataset. I've manage to create a function for reading and processing the models at once. The catch is that maybe is not such a good idea growing an array inside a for loop due to the complexity of the dataset, which could incore in some error.

How to build a function for that making use of the apply R's family functions?

## Here is the function I've made

```
require(raster)
require(abind)
require(rgdal)

myFunction <- function (x)
{
  directories <- list.dirs( x, full.names = TRUE)[-1]
  e <- extent(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  rcp <- NULL
  
  for (i in 1:length(directories))
  {
    models_raw <- stack(list.files(directories[i],pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE))
    models_e <- crop( models_raw , e ) 
    val <- values (models_e)
    coord <- xyFromCell(models_e, 1:ncell(models_e))
    models <- cbind(coord, val)
    models <- na.omit(models)
    rcp <- abind (rcp, models, along = 3)
  }

  return(rcp) 
} 

scenario <- myFunction( x = ".//data//models//")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply generalize your processing into a defined function with directory as a parameter, all to be called with `lapply`. At the end use a `do.call` to combine all models. There is no need for individual objects.

```
model_process <- function(dir) {
  model <- stack(list.files(dir,  pattern = ".tif$", full.names = TRUE))
  e <- extent(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  model_e <- crop(model, e)
  model_val <- getValues(model_e)
  coord_model <- xyFromCell(model_e, 1:ncell(model_e)) 
  model_final <- cbind(coord_model, model_val)
  model_final <- na.omit(model_final)

  return(model_final)
}

directories <- list.dirs(".//data//models//", full.names = TRUE)[-1]

model_list <- lapply(directories, model_process)

scenario <- do.call(abind, c(model_list, along=3))

# ALTERNATIVELY:
apn <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)
scenario <- do.call("apn", model_list)
```

Comment: Further simplification is possible with `model_final <- rasterToPoints(model_e)`

Comment: Even better @RobertHijmans if it works for OP. I am not famaliar with package or raster objects, so I defer to you practitioners.

Comment: Hi there @Parfait, your solution worked partially, Since my models are in subfolders of the directory .//data//models// I had to exclude it by adding [-1] in the directories line. But my problem is that in "scenario" my final result objected must have 3 layers. The function abind make this this with along = 3 . How to proper incorporate it there?

Comment: @MiltonAlves ... use the *args* argument of `do.call`. See edit.

Comment: @Parfait I've tried this. Keep getting: Error in if (quote) args <- lapply (args, enquote):
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (quote) args <- lapply (args, enquote):
  the condition has length> 1 and only the first element will be used
>

Comment: Inspect *model_list*. Does it correctly contain all your models? Can you code in long format: `abind(model_list[[1]], model_list[[2]], model_list[[3]], along=3)`. If so, try first three: `do.call(abind, model_list[1:3], args=list(along=3))`. One model could be the issue.

Comment: @Parfait yes my models are in model_list and Yes I've got it woking the long way and additionaly manage to create a function using a for loop (see my post edit). This is why I do not thing the problem is one of my models. Thanks for your help! I've tried your suggestion for your function and got the same error.

Comment: I see your solution and it is ill-advised to grow complex objects like arrays in a loop as you are with the *rcp* object. Please try my edits one more time even alternative. `do.call(fct, list_of_objs)` is the shorthand for `fct(obj, obj, obj, ...)`. Here, we create a list and then append in **one** copy rather than the many copies as you do.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Should it be `model_final <- rasterToPoints(model_final)` instead? Since the object model_e was converted in other processed objects.

Comment: Leave `...` as is, meaning it takes any argument. Did you still err out? Do be aware I also edited the original `scenario <- ...` line, no longer using *args*.

Comment: @Parfait It works with the alternate code. The first one still getting that error. Surprisingly I get the same result of using my own function, witch is different from the result I got doing the long way, one by one. Maybe this is due some particularity of the package abind...

Comment: @Parfait Does "apn" stand for Access Point Name? Anyhow, thank you for all your help.

Comment: Nope. It's just any name, shorthanded for *append* since you are doing so with arrays. It must be something about *abind* as that *along* argument may need to run for each item or once for all items. Glad to help. Should you have a raster specific issue still lingering above iterating through directories, consider asking a new question.